# Cross domain tracking - Wordpress and Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

Which is the best approach to automatically add the **_link GA action** to every outbound link that points to a certain domain?

e.g.

```
<a href="http://example.com/intro.html" onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://example.com/intro']); return false;">See my blog</a>
```

Comment: How would you normally add an onclick event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event handler to all links that point to a specific domain.

For example if the domain you are linking to is `example.com` and jQuery 1.0+:

```
var linksToHost = $('a').filter(function(){
    return this.host.match(/^example\.com$/);
})

linksToHost.bind('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    _gaq.push(['_link', this.href]);
})
```

You must also enable linking on the target site in order for link to work properly:
`_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);`